# awk grep or sed : how to match two files

Tags: awk, grep, match, between

(you're wonderful)

How can I pass arguments to awk or grep from a previous command ?

I want to match one field (*Username*) from two files:

**Expected result:**

```
firstname   Lastname  Username IPaddress
Mozes       Bowman    user1    134.244.47.32
Jazzmyn     Parrish   user2    3.249.198.34
Chet        Woods     user3    52.215.73.213
```

**From these 2:**

```
**file1**
IPaddress       Username
34.244.47.32    user1
3.249.198.34    user2
52.215.73.213   user3

**file2**
firstname Lastname   Username
Mozes     Bowman     user1
Jazzmyn   Parrish    user2
Chet      Woods      user3
```

**This is as far as I can go with:**

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' file1 | while read Username IP ; do grep $username file2 && echo $IP; done
```

**Resulting in IP shown on a new line each time:**

```
firstname   Lastname    Username
IPaddress
Mozes   Bowman  user1
34.244.47.32
Jazzmyn Parrish user2
3.249.198.34
Chet    Woods   user3
52.215.73.213
```

Comment: If the matching lines can appear in different orders between the 2 files or there can be lines that do not match between the 2 files then include those in your example as those both make it a harder problem than you've shown so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' f1 f2 | column -t
firstname  Lastname  Username  IPaddress
Mozes      Bowman    user1     34.244.47.32
Jazzmyn    Parrish   user2     3.249.198.34
Chet       Woods     user3     52.215.73.213
```

Used `column -t` for tabular output.

Comment: Thx, it works.If I understand it well the [ ] in the second { } takes arguments from the first [ ] in the form of variable a[] ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. We use array `a` to store key-value map with key as `$2` and value as `$1` from `file1`. Later from file2 we access same array using `$3` as key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {r[$3]=$0 ; next } { print r[$2]"\t" $1 }' $file2 $file1
```

**output**

```
firstname Lastname   Username   IPaddress
Mozes     Bowman     user1      34.244.47.32
Jazzmyn   Parrish    user2      3.249.198.34
Chet      Woods      user3      52.215.73.213
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following `awk` code. This will take care of case where we have spaces in user names too. Written and tested with same format as per OP's shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
  print "firstname   Lastname  Username IPaddress"
}
NR==1{ next }
FNR==NR{
  match($0,/^([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+/)
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",value)
  arr[substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)]=value
  next
}
{
  first=$1
  second=$2
  $1=$2=""
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
}
($0 in arr){
  print first,second,$0,arr[$0]
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  OFS="\t"                                           ##Setting OFS as tab here.
  print "firstname   Lastname  Username IPaddress"   ##printing header here.
}
NR==1{ next }                                        ##Checking condition if this is very first line of file1 then simply ignore it.
FNR==NR{                                             ##This condition will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  match($0,/^([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+/)         ##Using match function to match IP address in file1 here followed by spaces.
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                    ##Creating value which is substring of matched regex.
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",value)                      ##Substituting spaces till last in value.
  arr[substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)]=value               ##Creating array named arr with index of rest of value(apart from ip values followed by spaces in file1) and its value is variable value.
  next                                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  first=$1                                           ##Creating first which has $1 of current line.
  second=$2                                          ##Creating second which has $2 of current line.
  $1=$2=""                                           ##Nullifying $1 and $2 here.
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")                            ##Substituting spaces from starting with null.
}
($0 in arr){                                         ##If current line is present in arr then do following.
  print first,second,$0,arr[$0]                      ##Printing variables then current line followed by arr value.
}
' file1 file2                                        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

With the example in your question all you need is:

```
$ paste file2 file1 | sed 's/ *[^ ]*$//'
firstname Lastname   Username   IPaddress
Mozes     Bowman     user1      34.244.47.32
Jazzmyn   Parrish    user2      3.249.198.34
Chet      Woods      user3      52.215.73.213
```